# Pipes and Redirection

Tags: bash

I am new to Linux and trying to learn shell through some online resources and searches. My question is about pipes and redirection.I want to list "ls" a filename and directly input it to "cat" using pipe to see its content.
So what I am doing is:

```
ls chap*.pdf|cat
```

Also,I want to list 'ls" a file and input the filename to a file and then see the content of that file using "cat".

```
ls chap*.pdf> file1 < cat
```

It doesnt seem to work. Please help. Also what is the order in multiple redirection for commands to execute?
Thanks

Comment: (1) `cat` reads from stdin if not given anything on its command line, so it's reading the output from `ls` on stdin and writing that to its stdout, which is exactly what your command is telling it to do. (2) All commands in a pipeline run at the same time.

Comment: ...also, don't ever use `ls` programatically: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: ...so, read the above to understand why this is buggy: `cat $(ls -1 chap*.pdf)`

Comment: `< cat` is trying to _read from a file named `cat`_, not _run a program named `cat`_.

Comment: This really seems more like a request for handholding / tutorial instruction through shell _usage_ than a reasonable question about shell _programming_.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, if you haven't read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, please do. `xargs` doesn't fix its problems -- take filenames starting and ending with quote characters or spaces as an interesting example. :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj, ...`xargs` is only entirely safe when used with the GNU extension `-0`, and an input source that NUL-delimits filenames.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Pressed return too quickly. Filenames `can contain newlines` but never do. So in principle, you should absolutely terminate commands with a character that can't be present in filenames, but in general I'm not sure it's worth going on such a tangent, especially when a poster doesn't understand pipes/redirection. Obviously agree with `printf '%s\0' chap*.pdf | xargs -0` being preferable to `ls * | xargs -d '\n'`, since `ls` really isn't doing anything particularly important, but far too much emphasis is given to avoiding parsing `ls`, when beginning users make worse mistakes.

Comment: @BroSlow, as someone who's seen multiple TB of backups destroyed by a script that made assumptions about things that filenames never do and a buffer overrun that dumped garbage into a filename, I can't accept that kind of lax behavior.

Comment: @BroSlow, ...and, well, that's really the point -- some lessons you learn out of necessity, because without them you can't be reasonably effective, and some lessons you only learn if you're unlucky enough to get bitten by them hard -- or taught by someone who was. Teaching the latter ones helps folks not get bitten.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy There is still a difference between avoiding `evil` and other extremely dangerous ways of blindly executing unkown data, and allowing newlines in code. Again agree you're right, and there is some risk to allowing newlines, just don't think it's as bad as you're making it out to be. Certainly worth mentioning, but not the end of the world.

Comment: @BroSlow, ...extended my answer to cover `-d '\n'`. Had forgotten that it was a GNU extension (and, moreover, one not as widely adopted on BSDs as `-0` is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat` retrieves the list of files to concatenate **from its command line**, not **from its stdin**; pipes connect to stdin. Thus, you cannot pipe filenames into `cat` if you want it to print the content of those files, rather than their names.

The correct usage, instead of a pipeline, is to use shell globbing to fill out those names:

```
cat chap*.pdf
```

If you insist on piping in filenames, NUL-delimit them and use xargs -0, as `xargs` reads from stdin and puts what it reads onto the command line of software it runs:

```
printf '%s\0' chap*.pdf | xargs -0 cat
```

---

Use of `printf '%s\0'` and `xargs -0` is recommended above because using newlines for delimiters in UNIX filenames is unsafe because UNIX filenames can contain newlines. Think about what would happen if someone else had run:

```
mkdir -p $'chap\n/etc/passwd\n'
touch $'chap\n/etc/passwd\n/.pdf'
```

...your program would be unable to read this file, because of the newlines -- but if you did a *recursive* search, you'd also be printing `/etc/passwd` to the screen!

---

If you *are* going to use `xargs` without `-0`, however, at a very minimum use `-d '\n'` (if on a GNU platform and able to do so; on non-GNU systems -- unless, like MacOS, they copy the `-0` extension -- `xargs` is not advisable):

```
printf '%s\n' chap*.pdf | xargs -d '\n' cat
```

Be aware of the previously-given caveat about filenames containing newlines!